# django l10n dateformat goes wrong for only en

Tags: python, django, localization

I am working with l10n settings to translate my site.
All goes fine except for when the browser language is set to 'en'
When I print the get_language() and get the language date format. They return the correct values ('en', 'm/d/Y')

However when I check the date in my template, it is Y-m-d

For every other language it just works as it should

```
# settings.py
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'nl-NL'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True

# forms
# DatePickerForm is needed to also setup the bvootstrap-datepicker
class DatePickerForm(forms.Form):
""" hidden inputs to make bootstrap-datepicker work with django locale """

FORMAT_MAP = {
    # 'locale': [datepicket_lang, datepicker-pattern]
    # 'en-US': ['en', 'mm/dd/yyyy']
    'en': ['en', 'mm/dd/yyyy'],
    'nl': ['nl', 'd-m-yyyy'],
    'pl': ['pl', 'dd.mm.yyyy'],
    'de': ['de', 'dd.mm.yyyy'],
}

locale_language = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
locale_date_format = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.locale_language = get_language()
    super(DatePickerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.initial['locale_language'] = self.datepicker_language()
    self.initial['locale_date_format'] = self.datepicker_format()
    print self.locale_language

def datepicker_format(self):
    if self.locale_language in DatePickerForm.FORMAT_MAP:
        return DatePickerForm.FORMAT_MAP[self.locale_language][1]
    else:
        return DatePickerForm.FORMAT_MAP['nl'][1]

def datepicker_language(self):
    if self.locale_language in DatePickerForm.FORMAT_MAP:
        return DatePickerForm.FORMAT_MAP[self.locale_language][0]
    else:
        return DatePickerForm.FORMAT_MAP['nl'][0]

class TotalForm(DatePickerForm):
""" date range input for totals """

begin = forms.DateField(label='')
end = forms.DateField(label='')
```

Anyone has any idea why this is going wrong?